# Changing activity label color - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, themes

In my app i don't know how the color of activity label changed from white to black. I want to to make it white again. I tried various ways. Here are some pieces of code:

This is my action bar:

```
   <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.FlikrApp"/>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

This is my theme:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.FlikrApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/icons</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/primary_light</item>
        <item name="icon">@color/icons</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.FlikrApp.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.FlikrApp.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="Theme.FlikrApp.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

I tried this as well in `onCreate` method but didn't work:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font-color\"white\">Flikr App</font>"));
```

I added to my `themes` this as well but nothing

```
<style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Also tried changing `theme` and `popupTheme` of my tool bar but if it worked i won't be writting this.

Answer (score 0):

Use material design theme which automatically colors the statusBar as colorPrimaryDark value. Change your colorDarkPrimary according to the color of status bar you want.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

-<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<!-- Base application theme. -->



-<style parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar" name="Theme.StairwaysToSolutions">

<!-- Primary brand color. -->


<item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>

<item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>

<item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>

<!-- Secondary brand color. -->


<item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>

<item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>

<item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>

<!-- Status bar color. -->


<item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>

<!-- Customize your theme here. -->


</style>

</resources>
```

Save this file as themes.xml, and then in Manifest replace theme with this.

```
<application android:theme="@style/Theme.StairwaysToSolutions" android:supportsRtl="true" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:allowBackup="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me till now but then I came up with a way that has to do nothing with `theme.xml` file.

I added this to my `onCreate`

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

And then added a custom `TextView` in my ToolBar`:

```
   <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.FlikrApp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/custom_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"/>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

I literally tried everything possible to do this and I guess it was probably the last thing left to do and gladly it worked!